# Can I pass undefined parameter?

Tags: java, android

Can I pass undefined parameter like below example :

```
//This method not working with me
public void setValue(String key, Object value) {
    if (key.equals("isNewUser"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    if (key.equals("isNotificationEnabled"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    if (key.equals("userScore"))
        editor.putInt(key, value);
    if (key.equals("userName"))
        editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

These methods working with me using overload method like below :

```
public void setValue(String key, boolean value) {
    if (key.equals("isNewUser"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    if (key.equals("isNotificationEnabled"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public void setValue(String key, int value) {
    if (key.equals("userScore"))
        editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public void setValue(String key, String value) {
    if (key.equals("userName"))
        editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Is there any way to make it working with one method instead of 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to cast your `Object value` like below

```
if (key.equals("userName"))
    editor.putString(key, (String) value); // when you are sure that value IS String
```

additionally you may check instance by

```
if (value instanceof String)
    editor.putString(key, value);
```

btw. this doesn't look like a proper way to store data ("unified" method), sooner or later it will throw `ClassCastException`, it would be better to keep methods for every primitive/instance type

Comment: Can this be a use case for generics or am I getting this wrong ? Having `public void setValue<T>(String key, T value)` for example.

Comment: in some way yes, but [only whole class may be generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), not only single method in it (like your snippet), so this feature isn't usable for your case

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to do with one method, the overloading is the right choice in these cases, anyway if the parameters type is guaranteed by the key, the solution can be:

```
public void setValue(String key, Object value) {
    if (key.equals("isNewUser"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    if (key.equals("isNotificationEnabled"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    if (key.equals("userScore"))
        editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
    if (key.equals("userName"))
        editor.putString(key, (String) value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

This will compile and work but a ClassCastException can be thrown if the casting is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit cast will works. However you should pay attention on `NPE`

```
public void setValue(String key, Object value) {
    if (key.equals("isNewUser"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    if (key.equals("isNotificationEnabled"))
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    if (key.equals("userScore"))
        editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
    if (key.equals("userName"))
        editor.putString(key, (String) value);
    editor.apply();
}
```